# Ring of Quotients and the Radical of an Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of a commutative ring $R$ with identity. If $I$ is an ideal in $R$, then $S^{-1} (\mbox{ Rad } I) = \mbox{ Rad }(S^{-1} I)$

If $x \in S^{-1} (\mbox{ Rad } I)$, then $x = \frac{r}{s}$ for some $r \in \mbox{ Rad } I$ and $s \in S$. Hence, there exists an $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $r^n \in I$; moreover, since $S$ is multiplicative, $s^n \in S$. Therefore $\left( \frac{r}{s} \right)^n = \frac{r^n}{s^n} \in S^{-1}I$ which means $x = \frac{r}{s} \in \mbox{Rad }(S^{-1}I)$

If $x \in \mbox{ Rad }(S^{-1} I)$, then $x^n \in S^{-1}I$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and therefore $x^n = \frac{r}{s}$ with $r \in I$. But $x$ is also an element in $S^{-1}R$, so that $x = \frac{t}{k}$ for $t \in R$ and $k \in S$. This implies $\frac{t^n}{k^n} = \frac{r}{s}$ which happens if and only if there exists an $s_1 \in S$ such that $s_1(st^n - rk^n) = 0$ or $s_1s t^n = r s_1 k^n \in I$. Since $I$ is an ideal, $s_1^n s^n t^n = r s_1^n k^n s^{n-1} \in I$. Hence $x = \frac{t}{k} = \frac{s_1 s t}{s_1 sk}$ with $(s_1 s t)^n \in I$, which means $x \in S^{-1} \mbox{ Rad }(I)$.

How does this sound?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for the response. I had someone else read  the proof and they said they couldn't follow the second part at all. So I just wanted to verify that it is correct, hence my reason for asking it on MSE. Is the second part more complicated than it has to be? Perhaps that's why this person was confused.

Comment: I can also follow your argument just fine. Maybe you should ask that *someone* where exactly they could not follow.